# JPA Entity inheritance with two DiscriminatorColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, discriminator

I need your help.

I have the following table of values that I want with JPA map.

[image: Table to map]

I have considered the following class structure.

[image]

The classes "NotificationCustomShippingPlan" and "PreviewCustomShippingPlan" get everyone a DiscriminatorValue for DiscriminatorColumn "Type".

But the classes "ActivResultCustomShippingPlan" and "ActivResultCustomShippingPlan" should get other DiscriminatorColumn "SubType".

How can I so what map?

My feeling told me that it is not possible.

EDIT:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
@Table(name = "CC_CUSTOM_SHIPPING_PLAN")
public abstract class AbstractCustomShippingPlan {
....
....
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("NOTIFICATION")
public class NotificationCustomShippingPlan extends AbstractCustomShippingPlan



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("PREVIEW")
public class PreviewCustomShippingPlan extends AbstractCustomShippingPlan


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("RESULTS")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "SUBTYPE")
public abstract class ResultCustomShippingPlan extends AbstractCustomShippingPlan {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "CC_CSP_SUBTYPE")
    private ServiceType.Subtype subtype;

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ACTIVE")
public class ActivResultCustomShippingPlan extends ResultCustomShippingPlan{
    .....
}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("REPORTED")
public class ReportedResultCustomShippingPlan extends ResultCustomShippingPlan {
....

}
```

Comment: In the parent class, I think `AbstractCustomShippingClass`, you should have an annotation `@DiscriminatorColumn`. Change it's parameter `name` to `subType`. If you have not such annotation please provide some code.